# If statement over column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a column with data with values between 0 and 100. I want excel to give me the total number of data points that have a value larger than 50. How would I do that? I know how to use an IF-statement for a single cell, but I don't know how to loop appropriately in Excel over the column.

Comment: Use SUMIF and/or COUNTIF to get the total of the values over the limit and number of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in Column A, you can use the following formula to count values greater than 50.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,">50")
```

In order to sum up those values, you need to use SUMIF() function.

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">50")
```